# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : how to remove client-side library?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

In Solution explorer, right click on project -> Add -> Client-side library, we can add a new client-side library.

However, when I click on "Manage Client-Side Libraries", VS only pops up the `libman.json` file. And deleting the entry in `libman.json` does not help me remove the related files from the project.

What are the standard operations/steps to remove a client-side library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the light bulb icon that appears in the left margin, and select Uninstall ,then save the file(libman.json) ,the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-7.0#uninstall-library-files) related

[image]